# Are the ages of the original five X-Men ever stated?

Tags: marvel, x-men

I was looking through some of the old-school X-Men comics the other day, you know, the first set by Stan Lee and Jack Kirby? I noticed something odd, though: Iceman's age is the only stated age. At no point in the first couple of issues did I see an age for Cyclops, Beast, Angel, Marvel-Girl; not even one for Professor X. Am I missing something here, or are the original ages just plainly never stated? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well the old [stat cards](https://thecaptainbritainblog.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/captain-britain-marvel-universe-series-2-1991.jpg) never had any specifics. [Marvel Timeline](http://marvel.wikia.com/Marvel_Time) gives us a rough outline of how much time has past since 1961. Maybe you can figure it out - for instance according to the [Marvel Wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/Spider-Man_(Peter_Parker)) Peter was bitten on the hand by a radioactive spider at 15-yrs-old and the Marvel Timeline seems to say that that was about 15 yrs ago. Similarly you can look up & then sussout the age of the X-Men

Answer (score 3):

The ages of the characters were never plainly stated, at least not in the original run of *X-MEN* (before they became all-new, all-different, or uncanny). Based on the back-up stories from later issues in the series (running from issue 38 (Oct 1967) through 57 (June 1969)) that detailed how each of the  original five (except Marvel Girl) met Xavier and joined the team, the characters would seem to be in high school when they first appeared.

Hank McCoy somehow got a college degree without seeming to have taken time out to go to college (he's employed as a scientist by the early 1970's; Bobby Drake is shown in college a decade later). However, as Hank's clearly something of a genius, he may have been doing collegiate work via Xavier's school, even if the others were getting high school diplomas.

It's clearly intimated that Bobby is the youngest of the five in those early appearances, but not by a significant degree.